# Static class object property is undefined in run time

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am having a weird problem

I have this class

```
export class PageList {

  static readonly About: IPageInfo = Object.seal({
    menuTitle: 'About',
    url: 'about',
    trainingType: undefined,
    trainingName: undefined
  });

  static readonly PrivacyFull: IPageInfo = Object.seal({
    menuTitle: 'FullPrivacyDetails',
    url: 'privacy-full',
    trainingType: undefined,
    trainingName: undefined
  });
}
```

I am using it in a component in this way:

```
import { PageList } from 'src/app/models/classes/page-list.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-privacy',
  templateUrl: './privacy.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./privacy.page.scss']
})
export class PrivacyPage implements OnInit {
    onSeeAll() {
        this.navService.push(PageList.PrivacyFull)
    }
}
```

In `this.navService.push` I am getting the `PrivacyFull` static member with the `menuTitle` as `undefined`.

[image: Undefined]

Looking it in Chrome dev Tools says it is `undefined` but if I see the file (liked by DevTools) it is as I wrote it.

[image: Correct class]

I am doing something wrong here? I really do not see it.

Or is Typescript/Webpack compiling something in the wrong way?

EDIT: When I see the generated webpack module it is also undefined.

Edit In case needed, here my `package.json` dependencies

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.4",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-rate": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/market": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/music-controls": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/secure-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@saninn/logger": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "0.25.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-apprate": "1.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "1.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-market": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-music-controls": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": "3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.4",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^7.5.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^7.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^1.3.0",
    "@ionic/v4-migration-tslint": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.14",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.21",
    "@types/webaudioapi": "0.0.27",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^7.0.0-alpha.2",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngx-spec": "^1.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.10.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.2",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "run-s format:fix",
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {},
      "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-music-controls": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-secure-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-market": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I remember seeing that behavior but I cannot reproduce it. What version of Typescript do you use?

Comment: My `package.json` has `~3.1.6` but I see in `package-lock.json` that some angular dependencies use `3.2.4`

Comment: Since I have seen this in the past, I tend to use a singleton service with `readonly` member properties in this kind of situation.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I could try that, although I am pretty sure I will get some circular dependency in some place with that 

Comment: I don't see why using a service would cause circular dependencies. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtkyjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage-list.service.ts).

Comment: I had a Hard time with lazy loaded Ionic Framework Modals because they aren't really lazy loaded and I needed to put components in two modules with double services... Anyway that is why I said that. I think I will go with the service route. Still it would be good to know the cause of this weird behavior.